# Script stops when error.log rolls over

Tags: php, apache, drupal

I have PHP Drupal framework running in Apache server, one REST call sent to my Drupal will trigger one block of PHP code. This block of code will keep running for 3 days in backend to analysis data stored in local database and keep writing the analysis result to a text file.

Notice that the block of code is also under Drupal framework, it's not running independently. When the Apache error.log rolls over, this block of code will stop working. To continue my task, I have to send REST call again to trigger it.
When error.log rolls over, the log content will be pushed to file error.log.1, and a new error.log file will be created. My code keeps writing to log, I can't see any abnormal log at the end of error.log.1, the script just literally stopped.

Saying so much, just tried to explain my problem clearly.

Question: How to handle this? Should I change some configuration of Apache server? Or do I have to use independent script which doesn't depend on apache server?

Answer (score 0):

I found this page explaining how apache and system do the log rotation. It shows me the files I need to take care of if I want to resolve my issue.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-apache-on-an-ubuntu-vps